# How to handle exception in asp.net by just adding a single function in main code

Tags: asp.net

In normal c# code once we add the below mentioned code and can handle the exception where ever there is chances of crash.

But is there any code to add in asp.net where it can handle any type of crash in any page using single function.

NOTE : This is for C#, I want to know that is there any alternate option in case of asp.net

```
static void Main()
    {
        AppDomain app = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        app.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(app_UnhandledException);
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
    static void app_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("MyHandler caught : ");
        MessageBox.Show("Runtime terminating:");
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
aspx.cs code:
    protected void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //code goes here

        }
        catch (exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionHandle(ex);
        }
    }

    public void ExceptionHandle(Exception ex)
    {
        lblErrorMesg.InnerText = Messages.ApplicationError();
        LoggerHandler.ExceptionWrite(ex, this.GetType().FullName.ToString());


    }
    class file:
    using System.IO;
    using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging;
    public static class LoggerHandler
    {
         public static void ExceptionWrite(Exception ex, string strClass)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.StackTrace st = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(ex);
                    LogEntry Log = new LogEntry();
                    Log.Severity = System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Error;
                    Log.Title = strClass + ": " + st.GetFrame(st.FrameCount - 1).GetMethod();
                    Log.Message = ex.Message;
                    //write error here in database wherever you want
                }
    }
```